# Php page not updated with get ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

On my php project on the left I have a list of users and on click I open the detail from my db  in a div on the center using a JS function (in this example I simplify the function)

```
function openUser(id) {
link = "user.php?id=" + id;
window.open(link,"_self")}
```

On the detail div I add some user information with an ajax call.
The problem is that I open the user 1 and add to it some information, then I open user 2 and then again user 1, the information are not updated and I need to press F5.
I add a function to refresh the page when I load it and it works

```
window.onload = function() {
if(!window.location.hash) {
    window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
    window.location.reload();
}}
```

but I don`t like it and I would like to solve the problem in an other way.

Comment: An AJAX call won't refresh the page.  That's kinda the whole point in using it.  You should probably use another function to update the part of the page where you want the AJAX result shown.  Otherwise, you may as well just submit the page.

Comment: I know... I use ajax to add user information on a table in my db and it works. After successfully adding the information to user 1, if a open with the JS function the user 2 and then again the user 1, I get the information not updated...